# np.arange function returns weird value. I don't know why

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
a=np.arange(1e-10,2e-10,1e-11)
print(len(a))
b=np.arange(0.1,0.2,0.01)
print(len(b))
```

Value of a is 11 and value of b is 10. Why is that? I've known that arange func is the interval including start but excluding stop.

Comment: From the doc: 'When using a non-integer step, such as 0.1, the results will often not be consistent. It is better to use linspace for these cases.'

Comment: Value of a is 11 and value of b is 10. Why is that? Because your are printing the length of the array. And np.arange(0.1,0.2,0.01) [0.1 + 10 * 0.01] = 0.2 or [0.1 , 0.11, 0.12, 0.13, 0.14, 0.15, 0.16, 0.17, 0.18, 0.19]

Answer (score -1):

Because you are passing an exponentinal, **non-integer** value to the **step** parameter of the `arange` method. It may cause a not consistent output according to the official documentation.

Try using `linspace` method instead. Here is the point from the official documentatin for `numpy.arrange`;

> When using a non-integer step, such as 0.1, the results will often not
>   be consistent. It is better to use linspace for these cases.